Как сделать, чтобы фотография сразу загружалась в пост без предварительной загрузки в альбом?
vk.wall.post(owner_id=f"-{group_id}", message=message, attachments='photo-'+str(id_albom)+'_'+str(id_last_photo),  publish_date=int(publish_time.timestamp()))

Код выше публикует пост и вставляет фотографию из альбома. Вопрос: можно чтобы фотография сразу загружалась в пост без предварительной загрузки в альбом?
Или добавлять фото из директории или по прямой ссылке в интернете.

в этом методе еще есть параметр link_photo_id, но как я понял он должен передать id фото в альбоме вк. опять.

Загружай фото в альбом по апи
